# Jupyter Hub shows "Error Starting Kernel - Unhandeled error" without showing further information

Tags: error-handling, kernel, jupyterhub

I am using jupyter hub with [multiple users](https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).  I have created new environment few days ago. It seemed to work, I left it for few days, and today when I try to open notebook and set kernel I have pop-up  error message:

> "Error Starting Kernel - Unhandled error"
> [image]

I know two things that maybe related to this error:

1. The new environment set few days ago
2. I am running out of memory

I have read [this](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/5207) post  and I have chcked the version I have of jupyter_client (7.1.0) and jupyter_core (4.9.1) which seems to be more updated than the ones in the answer post, so I beleive that this is not the issue.

I have also tried to remove that environment but got error in the end:

> [Errno 28] No space left on device

I have also tried just to remove some files I have to have memory but the delet is failing.

I am not sure if the source of the error is the environment or the memory or both, but need some clue to solve it.
**My end goal is to have my jupyter hub working again- being able to set kernel and removing files.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had a similar issue and found the error regarding the logs. In my case, the issue was that the environment was located in the `/root/.conda/` directory, which resulted in a `PermissionDeniedError`. Here, moving the environment and installing the kernelspec as described in the [docs](https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/config-user-env.html#installing-kernelspecs) was the solution. You can do so with `conda create NAME -p /path/to/NAME` where `NAME` is the desired name of the environment and `/path/to/` should be a location accessible to all users.